# RSS FEED - data parsing

Tags: java, xml

How can I retrieve the location from following parsed data?

```
    <description>Origin date/time: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 04:23:32 ; Location: BLACKFORD,PERTH/KINROSS ; Lat/long: 56.284,-3.759 ; Depth: 7 km ; Magnitude: 1.0</description>
```

This details is within the description tag and description is already been parsed to an array list. How do just get the location out of it?

Comment: use a regular expression.

Comment: @OldProgrammer how do i do that? sorry im new to this

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I already parsed the description from the rss feed. Now i just need to retrieve the location from the array the description is stored

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash but how do i get the location from all the descriptions http://quakes.bgs.ac.uk/feeds/MhSeismology.xml

Comment: @R11 - Use `while` instead of `if` in my code. I've updated my code to reflect this change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex, `(?<=Location: ).*?(?= ;)` to find and extract the required match.

Solution using `Stream` API:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<description>Origin date/time: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 04:23:32 ; Location: BLACKFORD,PERTH/KINROSS ; Lat/long: 56.284,-3.759 ; Depth: 7 km ; Magnitude: 1.0</description>";
        
        List<String> list = Pattern.compile("(?<=Location: ).*?(?= ;)")
                                    .matcher(str)
                                    .results()
                                    .map(MatchResult::group)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[BLACKFORD,PERTH/KINROSS]
```

**Non-`Stream` solution:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<description>Origin date/time: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 04:23:32 ; Location: BLACKFORD,PERTH/KINROSS ; Lat/long: 56.284,-3.759 ; Depth: 7 km ; Magnitude: 1.0</description>";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=Location: ).*?(?= ;)").matcher(str);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            list.add(matcher.group());
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[BLACKFORD,PERTH/KINROSS]
```

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aEqVy9/1):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all you get is

```
Origin date/time: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 04:23:32 ; Location: BLACKFORD,PERTH/KINROSS ; Lat/long: 56.284,-3.759 ; Depth: 7 km ; Magnitude: 1.0
```

You're going to have to either (a) determine the standard that dictates this format if any or (b) do it yourself i.e. look at the structure and decide to parse based on that.

### Simple way with split()

It seems you can use the split() method on a String using separator " ; ". That should give you an array of length 5.

You could then assume Location is always in the second position or simply iterate over the array until you find the string that starts with Location.

#### Example

```
public class Location {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rawData = "Origin date/time: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 04:23:32 ; Location: BLACKFORD,PERTH/KINROSS ; Lat/long: 56.284,-3.759 ; Depth: 7 km ; Magnitude: 1.0\r\n";
        String[] dataArray = rawData.split(" ; ");
        System.out.println(dataArray[1]);
    }
}
```

### The Regular Expression Way

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression that could give you the value outright without going through the steps I just described. The value you are looking for is always preceded by `Location:`  and ends with `;` Have a look at this [primer to get going](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp).

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Location: ).*?;", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rawData);
    boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
    if(matchFound) {
      System.out.println("Match found: "+matcher.group());
    } else {
      System.out.println("Match not found");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary along with Regex :

```
           string pattern = @"(?'key'[^:]+):\s+(?'value'.*)";
            string input = "Origin date/time: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 04:23:32 ; Location: BLACKFORD,PERTH/KINROSS ; Lat/long: 56.284,-3.759 ; Depth: 7 km ; Magnitude: 1.0";
            string[] splitArray = input.Split(new char[] { ';' });

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = splitArray.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, pattern))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["key"].Value.Trim(), y => y.Groups["value"].Value.Trim())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            string location = dict["Location"];
```

---

Or this

```
            string pattern = @"(?'key'[^:]+):\s+(?'value'[^;]+);?";
            string input = "Origin date/time: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 04:23:32 ; Location: BLACKFORD,PERTH/KINROSS ; Lat/long: 56.284,-3.759 ; Depth: 7 km ; Magnitude: 1.0";
            string[] splitArray = input.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = matches.Cast<Match>()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["key"].Value.Trim(), y => y.Groups["value"].Value.Trim())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            string location = dict["Location"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
String desc = "Origin date/time: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 04:23:32 ; Location: BLACKFORD,PERTH/KINROSS ; Lat/long: 56.284,-3.759 ; Depth: 7 km ; Magnitude: 1.0";
String[] parts = desc.split(";");

for ( String part : parts )
{     
    if ( part.contains("Location") )
    {
        parts = part.split(":");
        
        System.out.println("***************** Location is: '" + parts[1].trim() + "'");

        break;
    }
}
```